# Oracle replace square brackets REGEX_REPLACE

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I have strings in one of my table in which I need to replace some specials characters like `' _ ? °` and square brackets `[` `]`.
When I try this it's working like expected :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BIG''EAST_?°[]', '[_?°'']', ' ') FROM DUAL;
```

I get:

```
BIG EAST   []
```

Then I add the square brackets in my regex :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BIG''EAST_?°[]', '[_?°''\[\]]', ' ') FROM DUAL;
```

I expected this:

```
BIG EAST
```

But I get:

```
BIG'EAST_?°
```

How can I properly escape the square brackets in my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a * to match multiple occurrences (and in any order) of characters from your pattern

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BIG''EAST_?°[]', '[_?°''\[\]]*', ' ') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: It's working perfectly with the sample and on my whole table, thx ! Now, is there a difference, performance side, with your answer and the one of J.Lee, wich is working perfectly too ?

Comment: @GuillaumeDeguines, I can't see that answer anymore, looks like it was deleted.

Comment: He was suggesting to do : `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BIG''EAST_?°[]', '[_?°''\[]|\]', ' ') FROM DUAL;`

Comment: @GuillaumeDeguines, I don't see any obvious reasons why one would be faster than the other since they are so similar.